# How to view Gmail account changes by administrator?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

In my company there was some mishap by admins and this lead to change employee Gmail account password resets several times (at least that is the reason that they give out for us).

What I need to know is there a way to get these password changes records (what I need is password change date, time and who invoked the reset password) just for my account?

ex -

```
password change : 2017/04/04 
reason : administrator reset
```

A record like above is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible to see in the *Admin console audit log*. If you are an administrator of the domain, you access it this way:

1. Go to http://www.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN.COM and log in.
2. Click Reports → Audit → Admin.

You should now see a table with the following columns (from Google's documentation):

- Event Name
- Event Description
- User

You are looking for a row where *Event Name* is something like *reset user password*, *Event Description* should mention the account being affected by this, and *User* would be the name of the administrator who performed the change.

See Google's documentation: https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579579?hl=en

---

If you are not an admin, your possibilities are limited. You may still be able to see when your password was last changed:

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com/ and log in
- Click *Sign-in & security → Google Login* in the left hand menu
- The right hand panel now shows some information, look for *Password - Last changed*.

Comment: the problem is i have to ask for admins to do this

Comment: @menaka If you're not an admin yourself, then I doubt you will have any luck finding out why your password was reset.

Comment: mmmm thanks m8, for trying if things get worse i might need to get legal help to extract those information from google...any advice for that ?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but that sounds nearly impossible. I don't see why Google would give away details about its customers' use of the admin tools.

Comment: @menaka See revised answer for some more information